# ESP32 can't enter interrupt anymore after interrupt appears during delayMicrosecond function

Tags: esp32, interrupt

I have a strange problem with my ESP32 project. I use an ADPS-9960 for gesture control which triggers an external interrupt. In the interrupt handler itself I only set a variable that causes the execution of a function in the loop. When I trigger an interrupt during the delay function the interrupt stops working. This means the loop is still running, but the interrupt routine doesn't get executed anymore.

```
#include <Arduino.h> 
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SparkFun_APDS9960.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
// Pins
#define APDS9960_INT    25 // Needs to be an interrupt pin

#define SERVO 4

// Constants
// Global Variables
SparkFun_APDS9960 apds = SparkFun_APDS9960();
int isr_flag = 0;
void IRAM_ATTR interruptRoutine();
int detectorPin = 19;

Servo myservo;

void setup() 
{
  // Set interrupt pin as input
  pinMode(APDS9960_INT, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("--------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("SparkFun APDS-9960 - GestureTest"));
  Serial.println(F("--------------------------------"));
  
  // Initialize interrupt service routine
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(APDS9960_INT), interruptRoutine, FALLING);
  // Initialize APDS-9960 (configure I2C and initial values)
  if ( apds.init() ) 
  {
    Serial.println(F("APDS-9960 initialization complete"));
  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.println(F("Something went wrong during APDS-9960 init!"));
  }
  apds.setGestureGain(GGAIN_1X); // ohne diese Zeile geht es nicht zuverlässig
  
  // Start running the APDS-9960 gesture sensor engine
  if ( apds.enableGestureSensor(true) ) 
  {
    Serial.println(F("Gesture sensor is now running"));
  } 
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("Something went wrong during gesture sensor init!"));
  }


  myservo.attach(SERVO);  
  myservo.write(20);

  pinMode(detectorPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if( isr_flag == 1 )
  {  
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(APDS9960_INT));
    handleGesture();
    isr_flag = 0;
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(APDS9960_INT), interruptRoutine, FALLING);
  }

  if(digitalRead(detectorPin))
    Serial.println("ON");

  else
    Serial.println("OFF");
}

void IRAM_ATTR interruptRoutine()
{
  if(isr_flag == 0)
    isr_flag = 1;
}


void  handleGesture() 
{
    if ( apds.isGestureAvailable() ) 
    {
      if( apds.readGesture() == DIR_FAR )
      {       
        Serial.println("FAR");
        myservo.write(165);
        delayMicroseconds (5000000);
        myservo.write(20); 
      }
      else
        Serial.println("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Comment: `isr_flag` needs to be declared as `volatile`. Please do this and try again

Comment: Hey @chrisl thanks for your reply. I changed it to `volatile int isr_flag = 0;`  but unfortunaltely the problem is still present.

Comment: Why are you using `delayMicroseconds()` for delaying 5s. I think the parameter type is only `unsinged int`. According to the Arduino documentation the max is 16383us. Please use `delay()` for such long delays. In older versions `delayMicroseconds()` also disabled interrupts. So that might be your problem

Comment: I used `dealyMicroseconds()` because I missunderstood the documentation of àttachInterrupt()` . Unfortunately using `delay()` didn't solve the problem, if an interrupt appears during the delay function I am still not able to enter the interrupt after this. The problem is very hard to localize as there seems no good way to debug in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Can you please check, when exactly the ISR is executed (especially after the first `delay()` call), by connecting a LED and toggling it in the ISR (but not in the if statement, just in the ISR)?

Comment: @chris Thanks again for the reply. When i make the gesture during the delay the ISR doesn't seem to be executed as the LED doesn't get toggled. 
I have looked in the reference example and I have noticed  something strange. They declare 2 as interrupt pin, but then use 0 in the attachInterrrupt/detachInterrupt, this have to be a mistake right? 
[link](https://github.com/sparkfun/APDS-9960_RGB_and_Gesture_Sensor/blob/master/Libraries/Arduino/APDS-9960_RGB_and_Gesture_Sensor_Arduino_Library/examples/GestureTest/GestureTest.ino)

Comment: Mhh, now I don't see any more reasons, why the ISR shouldn't trigger again after the 5s and the servo movement. Are you sure, that the delay is the problem? Maybe remove it and try again. I'm currently poking in the dark a bit

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure this has to do something with the delay, because when I use a gesture which causes a execution of the else block in `handleGesture()` there seems to be no problem. The thing I will try next is using a simple button for the external interrupt and look if anything changes. Thanks for your support so far!